# Display a specific error page when exception is thrown for user is Disabled in UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, thymeleaf

I have my UserDetails that is responsible for the login with isEnabled included so it prevent the user to login if not confirmed his email.I do this with a help of CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler to show the error with convenient messages in properties.

I have created an specific exception for that case (if the user is disabled). However when I do login with a disabled user, Spring app need to search for an "/error" page to display that (like there should be one error page named error.html).

I want to create my own html page that renders that specific exception to the user named "notconfirmed" 
btw (showing normal error in the same page doesnt help because the idea is to help user resend new confirmation link so that need I need a specific page)

My CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Component("authenticationFailureHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler  extends 
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;
    @Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, 
    final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException 
    exception) throws IOException, ServletException, MyException {
        setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=true");
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        final Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);       
        String errorMessage = messages.getMessage("message.badCredentials", 
        null, locale);
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

        if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User is disabled")) {
         /*     errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.disabled", 
            null, locale);
            System.out.println("user disable");*/
            //here where I throw the exception
            throw new MyException("User is disabled");
        }
   request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, 
   errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

My try on this was to create a function annotated with @ExceptionHandler in my LoginController redirecting to "notconfirmed" as below:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

 @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
 public String notConfirmedError(MyException e) {
    return "redirect:/notconfirmed";
    }

 @RequestMapping("/notconfirmed")
 public String notConfirmed(Model model) {
 return "notconfirmed";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work that way. An HTTP 500 error is shown with User is disabled message and On logs:

```
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template 
 "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the 
  configured Template Resolvers
```

Please HELP!!

Comment: Can you try `@ControllerAdvice` rather than `@Controller` on the class `LoginController`?

Comment: yes @Metroids I already tried that on the LoginController class but didnt work with me! Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Metroids can you take a look on my unanswered question? thanks for your help man!!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324479/how-to-get-the-result-from-dropdown-list-in-thymeleaf-and-use-it-as-a-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `DisabledException` should be thrown in that case. So I guess you can do the following:

```
@Component("authenticationFailureHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException, MyException {
    if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/notconfirmed")
                    .forward(request, response);
    } else {
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }    
}
```

}